# Google Cloud ML Engine: Trouble With Local Prediction Given saved_model.pb

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I've trained a Keras model using the `tf.data.Dataset` API and am trying to see if I've saved it (as `saved_model.pb`) correctly, so I can use it on ML Engine.  Here's what I've done:

```
estimator = tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(my_model)
# create serving function...
estimator.export_savedmodel('./export', serving_fn)
```

So now I'm trying to use `gcloud ml-engine local predict` to see if I can get a prediction back.  I'm doing:

```
gcloud ml-engine local predict --model-dir=~/path/to/folder --json-instances=instances.json
```

Unfortunately, I get:

```
cloud.ml.prediction.prediction_utils.PredictionError: Failed to load model: Cloud ML only supports TF 1.0 or above and models saved in SavedModel format. (Error code: 0)
```

So then I try adding `--runtime-version=1.2` to my command like this:

```
gcloud ml-engine local predict --model-dir=~/path/to/folder --json-instances=instances.json --runtime-version=1.2
```

and I get back:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.ml-engine.local.predict) unrecognized arguments: --runtime-version=1.2
```

Any idea what I'm doing incorrectly / how to fix?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the output of `saved_model_cli show --all --dir /path/to/folder`?

Comment: @rhaertel80 Hmm I get back that `IOError: SavedModel file does not exist at: path/to/folder` which is a bit strange, since I can see the `saved_model.pb` right there?

Comment: That is strange. You're pointing to the parent directory of `saved_model.pb`, right? What else is in the folder?

Comment: @rhaertel80 There's a folder called `variables` which contains `variables.data-00000-of-00001` and `variables.index`, which I think is expected?

Comment: Is this a model you're comfortable sharing with me privately? If so, can you email cloudml-feedback@google.com?

Comment: @rhaertel80 Unfortunately, I can't share it.  Is there another way to debug?

Comment: Is it possible that ~/path/to/folder is wrong? The error message from gcloud local predict and saved_model_cli both indicate as much. Double check the path. Perhaps you need to point to the parent directory or a subdirectory. Consider using the full absolute path to get rid of the ~.

Comment: @rhaertel80 of course you were right about the path, sorry for the hassle!

Comment: No worries. Just happy you found the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity: the problem turned out to be an incorrect path. If anybody else encounters this issue try using the full absolute path and ensure you are point to the directory containing the `saved_model.pb` file.